# MySQL update query with average from last 1 year

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am trying to update values from another table by taking averages for the last 1 year values. the query i have written below is definitely wrong as `AsOfDate` has not been included in query for table `b`, but is indicative of what i am trying to do. Thanks in advance.

```
update MT_1YR_AVG_EXGRATE a
join (select avg(ExchangeRate) as ExchangeRate, CurrencyId from Currency_Exchange_Rate_Data
        where BaseCurrencyId = "USD" group by CurrencyId) b
on b.CurrencyId = a.CurrencyId and b.AsOfDate <= a.AsOfDate and b.AsOfDate > date_sub(a.AsOfDate,interval 1 year)
set a.ExchangeRate = b.ExchangeRate
where a.ExchangeRate = null;
```

Comment: Put the asOfDate filters inside the inner query

Comment: It's not obvious how you want to use `AsOfDate`. Please describe the goal you're trying to achieve by this (especially the part where `AsOfDate` column is involved and the inner query).

Comment: I am using the AsOfDate from table Currency_Exchange_Rate_Data to select 1 year range using AsOfDate from MT_1YR_AVG_EXGRATE table. The objective is to take one year average of ExchangeRate and the date range is selected using the AsOfDate

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
update MT_1YR_AVG_EXGRATE c join (
select b.CurrencyId, b.AsOfDate, avg(a.ExchangeRate) as ExchangeRate from Currency_Exchange_Rate_Data a, MT_1YR_AVG_EXGRATE b
    where a.BaseCurrencyId = "USD" and a.CurrencyId = b.CurrencyId and b.ExchangeRate is NULL
    and a.AsOfDate <= b.AsOfDate and a.AsOfDate > date_sub(b.AsOfDate,interval 1 year)
    group by b.CurrencyId, b.AsOfDate) d
on d.CurrencyId = c.CurrencyId and d.AsOfDate = c.AsOfDate
set c.ExchangeRate = cast(d.ExchangeRate as decimal(19,5))
where c.ExchangeRate is NULL;
```

Comment: this does not seem efficient but did the trick if anyone has a better way please post.. Thanks